# Convert MySQL Limit arguments to number

Tags: javascript, mysql, rest

I have a trouble with my Rest call to MySql database.

I use JS object and send it by rest get call with java back-end.

```
    requestParams: {
        pageStart: 0,
        results: 10
    }
```

I have configured query for this request

```
"get-users" : "SELECT * FROM ${_dbSchema}.${_table} LIMIT ${pageStart}, ${results}"
```

But queryParams trensforms at back-end into strings and at the response I get this error

`{"error":500,"reason":"Internal Server Error","message":"DB reported failure executing query SELECT * FROM shema.user LIMIT ?, ? with params: {results=10, pageStart=0} error code: 1064 sqlstate: 42000 message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '10'' at line 1"}`

Can I resolve this problem in sql-query?

Comment: Just shooting in the dark, but have you tried appending a `;` at the end of the template query?, also enclosing in backticks ` ` ` the schema and table names. Also your error message shows that there is a parenthesis `(` char somewhere maybe if you showed us more code we could clarify the issue.

Comment: sorry, I've had mistake in my error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message:

> {"error":500,"reason":"Internal Server Error","message":"DB reported failure executing query SELECT * FROM shema.user LIMIT ?, ? with params: {results=10, pageStart=0} error code: 1064 sqlstate: 42000 message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '10'' at line 1"}

It seems that the numeric values in the `LIMIT` clause are being set as strings instead of numbers, because they are enclosed in single quotes e.g. `''0', '10''`, from the extract of the error notice, how each number (`0` and `10`) are enclosed in single quotes `'0'` and `'10'`.

Comment: java back-end encloses values in single quotes. I think it has security sense. I can't change java back-end code and my question was about ability editing mysql query

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you using Java or Javascript (presumably node.js), which ever the case, if the quotes are being placed by the JDBC connector or by the mysql-node libs, you can try building the SQL query string using native string functions and then just executing the query.